# Enums compareTo() method implementation

Tags: java

I have an example and i am confused at the output.

```
 enum Seasons {
    WINTER,
    SUMMER,
    SPRING,
    AUTUMN;
}
public class SeasonTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Seasons season1 = Seasons.WINTER;
    Seasons season2 = Seasons.SUMMER;
    Seasons season3 = Seasons.SPRING;
    Seasons season4 = Seasons.AUTUMN;
    System.out.println(season1.compareTo(season2));
    System.out.println(season3.compareTo(season4));
    System.out.println(season4.compareTo(season3));
    System.out.println(season2.compareTo(season1));
    System.out.println(season3.compareTo(season3));
    System.out.println(season1.compareTo(season4));
}
}
```

The last line returns -3. Why is that? It should return -1 as season1 is less than season4. Why it would return -3?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you decide it should return `-1`?

Comment: Enum's compareto just needs to return an integer. Not necessarily -1 or 1.

Comment: I am not deciding whether it should return -1, i saw an implementation of compareTo() somewhere and for that implementation if one object is less than the other, it was returning -1, i thought may be Enum itself, internally handles same concept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`compareTo()` is allowed to return any positive or negative number, or zero.

It has no need to specifically return +/- 1.

Comment: And if I had to guess, the implementation just subtracts the index of the parameter (AUTUMN: 3) from the index of the receiver (WINTER: 0), which is -3

Comment: [Enum Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo(E))

Comment: Specifically, the [Comparable Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) says `compareTo` "Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object."

Answer (score 3):

Enum compareTo() is substracting ordinal values, so in your case it is `WINTER.ordinal() - AUTUMN.ordinal() = 0 - 3 = -3`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming elements are ordered on integerly basis,

```
 enum Seasons {
    WINTER,   // 0  \
    SUMMER,   // 1   \
    SPRING,   // 2    \
    AUTUMN;   // 3   --- difference is 3 (subtraction gives -3)
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot huseyin, it means, they basically are compared using the ordinal.

Answer (score 0):

If the object (in this case enum) from which you are calling the compareTo() method is greater than the argument in it - it will return a positive integer (1, 2, ..., 323432, doesn't matter really)

If they are equal it will be exactly 0

If the calling object is smaller than the argument, then it is going to be smaller than 0 (-1, -2... etc).

When using it in if statements and booleans use the > and < operators for the smaller and greater cases, instead of using `== 1` or `== -1`